# error like [lab-user@studentvm 0 ~]$ oc get pods error: Missing or incomplete configuration info

Tags: openshift

[lab-user@studentvm 0 ~]$ oc get pods
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:

1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.

please tell how to run oc commands

Comment: I would edit this question with the command you are using tagged as code then on a new line state the error message that is returned.  It may be helpful to state which operating system the command is being ran on.

Comment: [lab-user@studentvm 1 ~]$ oc get nodes
error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:


  1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
  2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
  3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
[lab-user@studentvm 1 ~]$

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may solve the below web link, please visit once

http://www.freekb.net/Article?id=4497

or execute the below command and login

```
oc login api.openshift.example.com:6443
```

this will generate config file automatically